# Use OS-specific file dialog to relink layer when file moves?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, file-path, macos

When I move a file out from under QGIS, of course I have to tell the program where it moved to.

If you close a QGIS project and then move or rename a layer source file, you get a prompt when you reopen the project asking where you moved the file, and you can use a OS-native (in my case, MacOS-native) open-file dialog to indicate where the source file moved to.

However, when I move a source file while QGIS is open, I can't figure out how to get an open-file dialog to link it to the changed source file. All I get is a clunky built-in file navigator which is not intuitive to use.

My default now is to just close the QGIS project and reopen it when I move layer source files, but is there a better way?